# Does contraction of quantifiers require axiom of empty set?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

We can contract multiple unbounded quantifiers to one unbounded quantifier via the notion of ordered pair(or sequence). I am reading Devlin's book Constructibility, and he claims that a theory $T$ of the language of set theory which includes **axiom of empty set** and axiom of pairing can contract the quantifiers. Do we really need **axiom of empty set** here? Let's consider the case where we want to contract the unbounded existential quantifiers of $\Sigma_1$ formula to a single unbounded existential quantifier followed by a $\Sigma_0$ formula. For example we want to contract $\exists x \exists y \phi(x, y)$ where $\phi(x, y)$ is $\Sigma_0$. Then let's consider this formula $(\exists z)[z \text{ is an ordered pair} \land \phi((z)_1, (z)_2)]$. This is a $\Sigma_1$ formula and I think just axiom of pairing suffices to get
$$T \vdash \exists x \exists y \phi(x, y) \leftrightarrow (\exists z)[z \text{ is an ordered pair} \land \phi((z)_1, (z)_2)]$$
Where could be axiom of empty set used?